# Rails adding row to DB through admin approval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am making an application in Rails and I have Devise about to be included for users management. I have an index page where all the database rows are in with CRUD ability which is all good.

The functionality I'm after is that if a user wants to add a new row, they can go through and 'add' it but before it gets actually added, the request goes through to an admin, then the admin can hit 'approve' and then the row gets added.

The issue is me trying to get around the fact that the program would 'hold' an action of adding a row and the admin would approve it, then the program would let that action apply.

Thanks.

Comment: use callback before save send a link to admin on click of that link save the data in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going through the hassle of preventing saving the row to the DB (you'd have to cancel the saving in a `before_create` callback but keep the data somewhere anyway and pass them to admin for approval somehow), I'd do a much simpler approach.

Add another column to the table, boolean column named e.g. `approved` and by default show only all approved rows in the listing. When a user creates a row, save it with `approved = false` and let admins access these unapproved rows and approve them simply by setting `approved = true` or delete them if approval is denied.

Also consider creating a DB index for this column for performance reasons.

Comment: This is a much simpler approach and I think it is something that can be implemented quite easy. Thank you for your advice.